# Key Input Glitch in Java

Tags: java

So I followed [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/bWHYjLJZswQ) to get key input in my Java program, but when I execute the program and press the keys, the player object is unresponsive for a few seconds before disappearing completely. Eclipse tells me that public void keyPressed(key event e) and public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) override themselves, but other than that, the IDE tells me nothing.

Here's the code for the KeyInput class:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter {

private Handler handler;

public KeyInput(Handler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);
        
        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player) {
            
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) tempObject.setyvel(-5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) tempObject.setyvel(5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) tempObject.setxvel(-5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) tempObject.setxvel(5);
        }
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);
        
        if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Player) {
            
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) tempObject.setyvel(0);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) tempObject.setyvel(0);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) tempObject.setxvel(0);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) tempObject.setxvel(0);
            
        }
    }

}
```

}

I've put an instance of the handler and a KeyListener in the main class. I've also set x, y, getX, getY, setX, setY, setxvel, setyvel, setId, and getId in my GameObject class. I've put x += xvel and y += yvel in my Player class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @user15793316 If you mean import a module called java.awt.eventlistener or java.awt.event.listener, neither of those things seem to exist. What component are you referring to and what do you mean by focus?

Comment: should I use EventListener in the KeyInput class or in a separate abstract class?

Comment: The code shown seems to be correct. Assuming that this is the code that is executed: what is the code in `setxvel()` / `setyvel()`?

Comment: @ThomasKläger  public void setxvel(int xvel) {
  this.xvel = xvel;
 }
 
 public void setyvel(int yvel) {
  this.yvel = yvel; //this is in the GameObject class